# DataGridView Moving

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, row

I am trying to move selected rows from one DGV to another DGV at the click of a button.

I really don't know where to begin..

I have two seperate DGVs that are bound by a DataSource..

```
choiceDGV.DataSource = theChoiceList;
universalDGV.DataSource = theUniversalList;
```

I would like to move any selected items in the `choiceDGV` to the `univeralDGV` by a click of a button. I need to make sure the selected rows are removed from the one DGV and added to the 2nd DGV.

Both of the `DataGridView`'s have the same amount of columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035865/how-do-i-move-row-from-one-datagridview-to-another-datagridview

Comment: @S.Amani: I tried that post and it hadn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in choiceDGV.SelectedRows)
{
     universalDGV.Rows.Add(row);
     choiceDGV.Rows.Delete(row);
}
```

or (edited: DataGridViewRow doesn't have ItemArray unfortunately):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in choiceDGV.SelectedRows)
{
     object[] items = new object [row.Cells.Count];
     for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
         items[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
     universalDGV.Rows.Add(items);
     choiceDGV.Rows.Delete(row);
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing this and the logic seems like it would work.. it just isnt moving anything. I am wondering why it doesn't.. hmm

Comment: I figured out I needed to have the entire row selected when clicking on a single cell. I used this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285829/datagridview-how-to-focus-the-whole-row-instead-of-a-single-cell) to do that. So now my error that I am getting is: `Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows colletion when the control is data-bound.`

Comment: I looked at your comment in other answer and found what is the type of data in your datasource, so I would try to do sth like:
theUniversalList.Add(new LoadLine(items[0], items[1], .../*or any form your LoadLine constructor accepts*/)); instead of universalDGV.Rows.Add(items); Then theUniversalList.EndEdit() (not sure if it is actually needed) and rebind DGV. Hope that helps

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But how do I get the `items[0], items[1], ...` from the other DGV?

Comment: as I did in my original answer:
for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
         items[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the issue. You just need move the items you like to the UniversalList within the onclick button handler and call `.DataBind()` on both the datagridview.
In other words you have to hit the lists(datasource) instead of the data grid view

Comment: server side. Your binding logic and how you populate the lists

Comment: `theChoiceList.Add(new LoadLine(theChipList[count].Name, theDataBaseList[i].PlacingTime, ...a total of 14));`

Comment: So would I do something along the lines of: `foreach(var row i nchoiceDGV) { theUniversalList.Add(row); theChoiceList.Remove(row); }` ? *(this does not work btw)*